# A sequence that Has three limit points

Tags: real-analysis

Construct a sequence that has exactly three limit points at -∞,∞,0?

I chose (an)=(1/n+k)_n>=1 with k belong to the extended real numbers. But I still can not prove that -∞,∞ are limit points, moreover I found this sequence has a limit point at k not zero, so I will appreaciate any help for this?

Comment: Your sequence must have three subsequences, one converging / diverging to each limit point.

Comment: Your proposal is pretty clumsy, sorry to say. You may not use extended real numbers and in any case, your sequence tends to a *single* limit point which is $k$ (whatever that is).

Answer (score 1):

Try
$$
a_n = \left\{ \matrix{ n & n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\ -n&n \equiv 1 \pmod 3
\\ \frac2n &n \equiv 2\pmod 3} \right.
$$

Comment: why 2/n has also n≡0 (mod3)

Comment: Did you mean n≡2 (mod3)

Answer (score 1):

Look at $a_n=n\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}2\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be a monotone sequence tending to infinity. Let $b_n$ be a monotone sequence tending to negative infinity. Let $c_n=0$. Then, define the sequence $d_{3i} = a_n, d_{3i+1} = b_n, d_{3i+2} = c_n$.

If you take the subsequence of indices which are multiples of 3, it tends to infinity, multiples of 3 plus 1 it tends to -infinity and then multiples of 3 plus 2 it is identically zero. So, clearly you have the desired limit points.

Now, if you have a number which is non-zero, $x$ it cannot be a limit point. Why? For sufficiently large $n$, every value of $d_n$ will be either $0$ (if $n=3i+2$, so this will be $x$ far away) or greater than $|x|+1$ in absolute value (since $d_{3i},d_{3i+1}$ tend to infinity in absolute value, they will eventually be bigger than $|x|+1<\infty$ in absolute value).

Thus, the only limit points are $-\infty,\infty,0$.

Comment: Concrete example: $n\sin(2\pi n/3)$.